# Remmina Issues (VNC) on Ubuntu 22.04 with X (not Wayland)

Tags: 22.04, vnc, remote, remmina

I am currently in the process of updating a lab full of computers running Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. I am using Remmina from a computer running Ubuntu 16.04 to another computer running Ubuntu 22.04. I am using VNC as the protocol, not RDP. Both towers are using X for their window manager, not Wayland. There are two issues that I have for which I cannot find a resolution and they do not occur when I try to use Remmina over VNC to connect to another computer using Ubuntu 16.04, only Ubuntu 22.04. These issues are:

1. When I remotely connect to the Ubuntu 22.04 tower (which has two screens), I can only see the left most screen. When doing so using Remmina to connect to a 16.04 machine, there is a horizontal scroll bar that allows me to scroll through both monitors, but despite all of the options in Remmina, I cannot find a way to access the second monitor at all.
2. Only a single user can remotely access the machine running Ubuntu 22.04 at a time (using VNC and Remmina on both machines trying to remotely access the 22.04 machine). The second computer just immediately gets a dialog that states "VNC server closed connection." This was not the case with Ubuntu 16.04. I have no idea what type of setting would control this, but I would like to be able to access the machine by as many others concurrently as possible.

Any assistance with either of these issues would be most appreciated.