Remmina with VNC not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04
I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. I used Remmina daily to connect to the desktop remotely, however, the connection won't work now.
I have read multiple threads and tried many suggestions unsuccessfully. The remmote Remmina says "VNC server closed connection".
The host and the remote computers have "Sharing" turned on and allow "legacy VNC protocol".
Any suggestions on how to connect both computers?.

This might be very similar to a previous question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508953/remmina-issues-vnc-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-x-not-wayland

You are right. The solution in the suggested link solved my issue as well.
